# Where is the best place to start looking for Haskell Developers?

Tags: haskell

I'm looking to hire developers for a project and most people I speak with have experience with Solidity and therefore trying to convince me to focus on the Ethereum ecosystem.

I like what the Cardano community is doing, especially the Founder's vision and approach, and accordingly want to focus on the Cardano ecosystem. I'm therefore looking for developers with Haskell experience and don't know where to start. Is there an area within the Cardano community to specifically post jobs and recruit individuals desiring to work on Cardano?

Comment: Keep doing that^, and they will come.

Answer (score 1):

You can post your opportunities on *IOHK* discord. There is a `#post-a-job` channel, under `Lounge` category.

Answer (score 1):

I find the Haskell to be still rather niche language, meaning not so many developers out there, thus it's difficult to find someone on common boards.
I would agree with the others that it's a good idea to be looking specifically around Cardano, Haskell and functional programming communities

1. A nice place worth checking is [functional.works-hub.com](https://functional.works-hub.com/)
2. [functionalprogramming.slack](http://functionalprogramming.slack.com) has numerous channels for job postings (#jobs, #haskell-jobs)
3. Cardano official developer community [list](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardano-developer-community/)

Answer (score 0):

The best places to start looking for Haskell developers are [*Reddit*](https://www.reddit.com/r/cardano/), *LinkedIn* and *StackOverflow* – there is at least a hundred of seasoned Haskell developers on those resources.